# Ansible: Replace values from one dictionary to another without adding entire dictionary

Tags: python, ansible

As the headline suggests, I'm looking to combine 2 dicts in that if the key of one dict is found in the other; the value of the the second dict is used.

For example

Dict 1:

```
{
  "test": "replace me",
  "test2": "some value"
}
```

Dict 2:

```
{
  "test": "replaced",
  "test3": "Don't add"
}
```

Combined result:

```
{
  "test": "replaced",
  "test2": "some value"
}
```

Comment: You might want to check on dict.update()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The playbook below

```
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    dict1:
      test: "replace me"
      test2: "some value"
    dict2:
      test: "replaced"
      test3: "Don't add"
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        dict1: "{{ dict1|combine({item: dict2[item]}) }}"
      loop: "{{ dict1.keys()|list|intersect(dict2.keys()|list) }}"
    - debug:
        var: dict1
```

gives

```
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

...

ok: [localhost] => {
    "dict1": {
        "test": "replaced", 
        "test2": "some value"
    }
}
```

Comment: trying to use this and I'm not sure I'm understanding how to access "facts"

Comment: `---
- name: Deploy and Update Lambda
  hosts: localhost
  # gather_facts: no
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: command
      command: "echo 'test'"
      set_fact: 
        dict1: "{{list.0.env_vars}}"
        dict2: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', vault_string)}}"

    - name: vault 2
      set_fact:
        dict1: "{{ dict1|combine({item: dict2[item]}) }}"
      loop: "{{ dict1.keys()|list|intersect(dict2.keys()|list) }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_facts }}"
`

This is what I'm posting but it throws an error if I try to use set fact in more than one task